# Using Typeahead and AngularJS with loaded data in scope results in "TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead

When trying to use [this concept](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1neIS?p=preview) for a typeahead, I created the following code (which works with the json data, just not with this new data).:

HTML

```
<input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead="suggestion for suggestion in instObjs($viewValue)">
```

JS

```
function NavbarCtrl ($scope, cService, $http, limitToFilter) {

  $scope.institutions = [];

  cService.getInstitutions().then(function(institutions){
    $scope.institutions = institutions;
  });

  $scope.instObjs = function(institutions) {
    return $scope.institutions.name.then(function(response){
      return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: looks like `$scope.institutions.name` is undefined, which makes sense if `$scope.institutions` is an array.

Comment: @basilikum It's an array of objects. The objects have the `name` parameter. I want to search on everything in those objects.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you are trying to use `$scope.institutions.name` before it gets assigned. I suppose, that $scope.instObjs is called before your callback to `cService.getInstitutions()` is called.

But this is a **consequence**, not **cause**.

I can see you are trying to access property name of array. Are you sure you didn't mean something like this:

```
$scope.instObjs = function(institutions) {
    return institutions.name.then(function(response){
      return limitToFilter(response.data, 15);
    });
  };
```

I mean using your function's parameter instead of array. That would make a sence. And this can be a **cause**.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've actually tried this as well and get the error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'then' of undefined` But you are correct, I'm trying to use this to perform a typeahead search on the name (or any) parameters.